# gcloud array syntax for adding multiple values in a patch call

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, gcloud

I've installed `gcloud` to manage the relationship between my CloudSQL instances and my GAE apps.

I have a handful of apps that need to connect to one of the databases, and I'm attempting to automate the process of adding new GAE apps as authorized on this db, as part of streamlining a deploy process.

I'm trying to use the `patch` command, but for arrays, it overwrites the full value, so I need to pass a full array. Except, I'm unable to figure out the precise syntax for doing so. This is my best guess.

```
$ gcloud sql instances patch projectname:databasename --authorized-gae-apps="testappid1,testappid2" 

This command will change the instance settings.
All arrays must be fully-specified. Any previous data in an array will be overwritten with the given list.
The following JSON message will be used for the patch API method.
{'instance': 'test', 'settings': {'authorizedGaeApplications': ['testappid1,testappid2']}}
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.patch) ResponseError: status=400, code=Bad Request, reason=invalid
message=Invalid Value
```

It appears it's sending the apps as a string within an array, rather than separating each value out. I've tried a few other approaches, but none that I've tried successfully translate the command line arguments into multi-item arrays in the JSON.

If I do something like this (set only one app), it works, but it overwrites the full value, which is not what I want:

```
gcloud sql instances patch projectname:databasename --authorized-gae-apps="testappid1"
```

How can I get `gcloud` to let me specify multiple authorized GAE apps from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

`gcloud sql instances patch projectname:databasename --authorized-gae-apps testappid1 testappid2`